# Is Java's heap space organised as a binary tree

Tags: java, heap-memory, heap, b-tree

I read that the 'heap' is basically a binary tree. But this definition of Heap got me thinking about Java's Heap Space. Java's heap is a place where all the objects are created. But these objects surely are not sorted as per a binary tree?
Because what would be the purpose of that?

Comment: You're thinking of [*a* heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), not [*the* heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(programming))...

Comment: The simple answer is no, it's a more complex answer which is related to the idea of garbage collection. Generally the Java heap space is managed by dividing into different regions where each region will be assigned its own memory pool. Take this blog [Understanding Java Heap Space and Memory Tuning](http://www.ashishsharma.me/2011/08/java-heap-space.html) for reference. You can also read the [Oracle Java memory management whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binary heap is a heap data structure created using a binary tree while java heap is the memory used by JVM to manage the objects. You seems to be confused between these two concepts.

Datastructure such as [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) uses the binary heap tree concepts.